# how to remove selected items in the select option in webform matrix component

Tags: hooks, webforms

I have 10 values in the select option component (i.e dropdown box)

for example
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Once I have selected 1 value, That value should not repeated again in the select option (i.e dropdown box) 
Example 
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Please guide me how to find the solution for this
Thank you

Comment: You need to do it with JavaScript...